# Adding Buttons dynamically in RelativeLayout to LinearLayout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

When the user inputs a word, he creates a number of `Buttons` equal to the length of the word. For example: if user inputs `"aaaa"` he will create 4 `Buttons`, side by side, in the first row. Then if the user enters `"bb"` he will create 2 `Buttons`, side by side,  in the second row. And `"ccc"` he creates 3 `Buttons`...

Image to demonstrate:

[image]

I dynamically create a `RelativeLayout`, then dynamically add `Buttons` to that layout. And finally I add the `RelativeLayout` to my existing `LinearLayout`. But the problem is, only one `Button` is added per row. And my program currently looks like this:

[image]

Can someone please me fix this problem?

CODE:

```
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_bttn_words);

    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    button_test.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(view.getContext());

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    


                    int size = enter_txt.getText().toString().length(); //the user input number of buttons

                    int id = 1;

                    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
                    {
                        Button myButton = new Button(view.getContext());

                        myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);

                        myButton.setId(id);

                        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, myButton.getId());

                        relativeLayout.addView(myButton, rlp);

                        id++;
                    }

                        linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout, llp);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, myButton.getId());
```

This line says that myButton should be added to right of myButton, which doesn't make any sense.

simple way to resolve this is to use the following line instead

```
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, myButton.getId()-1);
```

But this isn't the best way to do this, you should use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation instead.

Comment: hm, there must be some more bugs. the program is still not wokring. I will try to do it perhaps in a LinearLayout like you suggested. I'm just so used to using vertical orientation I forgot there was a horizontal...

Comment: try incrementing the `id` before the line `myButton.setId(id);`

Answer (score 1):

The structure should be simple

Just need to add your buttons in 3 different linear layout with orientation horizontal.

Like

```
<Relative layout>{
<LinearLayout global container with vertical orientation >{
<LinearLayout for 'a' type buttons container with horizontal orientation>
<LinearLayout for 'b' type buttons container with horizontal orientation>
<LinearLayout for 'c' type buttons container with horizontal orientation>
}
}
```

Comment: is that in the xml? I chose to program it dynamically since the user can keep entering words. It's not only three words. The user may enter 20 different words so that's 20 rows of buttons

Comment: you need to create layouts in xml just need to create words on user input

Comment: also for more words you also need to create horizontal scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You guys are right. It is much easier using a LinearLayout. For those interested

```
final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_bttn_words);

final LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

button_test.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());

                    linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      

                    int size = enter_txt.getText().toString().length();
                    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
                    {
                        Button myButton = new Button(view.getContext());
                        myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
                        linearLayout2.addView(myButton, rlp);
                     }
                     linearLayout.addView(linearLayout2, llp);
```